# Python flask @app.errorhandler(Exception) get full error not just description

Tags: python, flask, error-handling

While making an intentional 500 error in flask and trying to catch it I'm not getting the description of the error is there a way to get the full error, not just the description?

> name 'params' is not defined

Code I'm using:

```py
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_exception(e):
    if isinstance(e, HTTPException):
        response = e.get_response()
        response.data = generate_error_json(e.code, e.name, e.description)
        response.content_type = "application/json"
        return response

    # e-> name 'params' is not defined
    logger.error(e)
    return "Server Error", 500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the stack trace then use this

```
import traceback

@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_exception(e):
    #Use for stack trace
    return traceback.format_exc()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will handle the `HTTPException` whilst retaining the built-in logging mechanism.

```py
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException
from flask import render_template
import sys, traceback

@app.errorhandler(HTTPException)
def httpexception(e):
    info = sys.exc_info()
    return render_template('error.html',
                           name=info[0].__name__,
                           message=info()[1],
                           traceback=traceback.format_exc(),
                           e=e), e.code
```

It will pass the HTTP error code, HTTP error message, the exception class name, the exception message, and the traceback to the template.

```html
{% block content %}

<h1>{{ e.code }} {{ e.name }}</h1>

<p><strong>{{ name }}: {{ message }}</strong></p>

<pre>
{{ traceback }}
</pre>

{% endblock %}
```